# El uso de "para que" y de "si" en ejemplos

Tags: gramática, subordinadas

Tengo preguntas.

1) En este diálogo,

-¿De quién es el coche aparcado delante de nuestro garaje? Ese coche blanco.
-¡Si es el coche de Juan! Ya no reconoces ni el coche de tu hijo, ¡increíble!

¿qué significa "si" en este caso, cómo se dice esta oración (con la palabra si) en inglés exactamente? La palabra "si" significa "whether, if", pero no tiene sentido en este contexto. ¿Quizás se usa "si" para poner énfasis en algo (como "que sí...")?

2) Tengo que hacer la proxima tarea:

"Usted organiza una fiesta con amigos. Lea lo que dicen. ¿Qué piensa que han traído?

1. Para que bailemos.
2. Para que no tengamos que lavar las copas.
   ..."

Similar como mi primera pregunta.. Claro, son oraciones abreviadas, pero me pregunta que significa "para que" en este contexto exactamente (yo sé que "para que" significa "such that").

(La propesta de solución de libro de 1 y 2 es:
1. Unos cedés.
2. Unas copas de plástico.)

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con respecto a la pregunta (1), el DRAE recoge este uso de "si" en la acepción (5):

> 5. conj. U. a principio de frase, da énfasis o energía a las expresiones de duda o aseveración. ¿Si será verdad lo del testamento? ¡Si dije que esto no podía parar en bien!

Este "si" es una conjunción y no debe confundirse con el adverbio de afirmación que lleva tilde. Observa la diferencia:

A) Conjunción "si":

-¿De quién es el coche aparcado delante de nuestro garaje? Ese coche blanco.

-¡**Si** es el coche de Juan! Ya no reconoces ni el coche de tu hijo. ¡Increíble!

B) Adverbio "sí" (con tilde):

-Ese coche blanco aparcado delante de nuestro garaje no es de Juan(, ¿no?)

-¡**Sí**, es el coche de Juan! / ¡**Sí** que es el coche de Juan! Ya no reconoces ni el coche de tu hijo. ¡Increíble!

Mientras que en (A) "sí" simplemente introduce la respuesta "es el coche de Juan", en (B) "sí" (o "sí que") tiene el efecto de afirmar como respuesta a la negación del interlocutor, que no cree que sea el auto de Juan.

En inglés (suponiendo que ese sea tu idioma nativo), (A) podría equivaler a *Come on, it's Juan's car*, mientras que (B) equivaldría a *Yes, it is Juan's car / It is Juan's car indeed.*

En respuesta a (2), "para que" introduce la finalidad o el propósito, y sería equivalente a *so that* o *for the purpose of*.

- Para que bailemos (*So that we can dance / For us to dance / For dancing*)
- Para que no tengamos que lavar las copas. (*So that we won't need to wash any glasses*)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own questions in the text.

Q1 - the respondent is surprised because the questioner (John) should have recognised his son's car. There must be many ways of saying this in English, perhaps starting the sentence "But is it .." would be one.

Q2 - yes the clauses give the reason for the preceding action which was to be supplied. They brought plastic cups so we did not have to wash the glasses.